# The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined -in Trustwallet

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, react, polygon, trustwallet

I'm getting this `The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined` error while confirming transaction on trustwallet.

The same payload works on Metamask. What could be the issue here?

[image: It shows The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined]

Comment: What did you do to get that error message?